# How to create training set? - Text classification

Tags: text

i like to create a text classifier that will classifying music lyrics to it's related category.
After I read some related research, they said that, firstly we need to create training set by using some document manually.
But, is that really manual? I mean, do we grouping the training set documents with no guide or some technique?
I really need some clear explanation or advice about this topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may split the set of samples into training set and test set. For instance, you can use 70% of samples as training set and the 30% remaining as test set. If should be done randomly.

Comment: @hfernandez - I don't think the person wants to know how to split the entire sample in to training and testing set.

Answer (score 0):

That yound's like you want to apply machine learning techniques on that problem. That is, you have a set of features derived from your lyrics (e.g. frequency of key words or similar, although I've never dealt with this specific problem) which are mapped to some labels (Pop, Rock etc).

Now a machine learning algorithm needs some reference classifications since it has no idea what words occur in a pop song more often than in a rock song.

It doesn't matter where they come from, you could take the classification from a charts list (pop charts, rock charts etc), e.g. you take a list of songs from each of the charts and supply the lyrics together with the respective label to the learner.
In that case the outcome would be a prediction model within which of these charts a new song would show up in.

Alternatively you manually define the training set, with lyrics and labels. It completely depends on what you want to learn. If you plan to create your personalized library it would make sense to use your manually defined test cases. If it's rather about testing the algorithm or similar use some easily accessible data like charts. In that case you'd attemp to learn the "black-box" method, that decided to which chart a certain song belongs (e.g. the taste of music of the person who created the cart list).